# Issue in Hibernate and JPA with Postgres while creating a attribute with "Date" datatype

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a table using hibernate and JPA with Postgres , and In one of the POJO, I have a timestamp attribute with Data type Date(java.util.date). and when I see it in Postgres it's converted to data type "date without timezone" while I want date with timezone, What should I do now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have different types of `Date`:

1. **DATE** to save a date without time information,
2. **TIME** to store a time without a date, and
3. **TIMESTAMP** to store date and time information.

And to map our variable to the specific type, we have to use `@Temporal` tag:

Small Example:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
     
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date utilDate;
     
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Calendar utilCalendar;

    // Getters, Setters ...
}
```

So I would suggest you save it as a **TIMESTAMP**

To specify the Time Zone in your Propeties file, use:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
```

If you DON'T want to use `@Timestamp`, just declare your variable/column this way:

```
@Column
private LocalDateTime created;
```

And it will be automatically mapped by Hibernate into a Timestamp for your Postgresql.

Comment: TemporalType is a better solution. One another might be to provide columnDefinition with column annotation on attribute and it will take whatever datatype you provide in columnDefinition.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But the best solution would be to use `LocalDateTime` since it is part of the new Time api. Still, your comment adds yet another solution.